# Transferring dynamic data using imports/exports

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, processing, p5.js

I have two P5 scripts running synchronously:

**A.** Continuously populates an object with fresh data using posenet and the webcam.
**B.** Dynamically draws on the canvas using said data

What is the best practice to get the data from file A to file B in real time, using ES6 modules (webpack)? Is it better practice to store the data in a separate json file?